# UIcollection view multiple selection deselecting cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a *collection view* with two *customs cells* and I have a method that when selecting a cells a boarder appears on selected ones, and a button that cancel all selections, the problem is when the button is pressed the cells borders are set to clear color but when go to selection mode again the previously selected cells still have the borders, so what am looking for is when I cancel the selection and then again go selection mode no cell should be selected, here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if isGridSelected {

        let cell:cell2_Class = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell2_Class

        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        collectionView.allowsSelection = true

        cell.listImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

        if self.selectedIndexes.indexOf(indexPath) == nil || cancel == true {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

            // Unselected
        }
        else if cancel == true { cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            for indexPath: NSIndexPath in selectedIndexes {

                self.collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor // Selected
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
        }

        return cell
    }
}

var flag = false

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if flag == false{ self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showimage", sender: self)  }

    else if cancel == true {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.selected = false

        // deselect
    } else if flag == true {

        if let indexSelection = selectedIndexes.indexOf(indexPath) {
            selectedIndexes.removeAtIndex(indexSelection)

        } else {
            selectedIndexes.append(indexPath)
        }

        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }
}

func handleLongPress(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)      {
    if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        return
    }

    let p = gestureReconizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)

    if indexPath != nil {

        if let indexSelection = selectedIndexes.indexOf(indexPath!) {
            selectedIndexes.removeAtIndex(indexSelection)
        } else {
            selectedIndexes.append(indexPath!)
        }
        print(indexPath?.row)
        cancel = false
        flag = true
        self.title = "share photos"
        cancelButton.hidden = false

    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: still working on it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you press `cancel` you call `self.collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)` for all `indexPaths` in `self.selectedIndexPaths`, put I don't see anywhere in your code that this **removes** them from `self.selectedIndexPaths`, is that right?

Instead try this

```
else if cancel == true { 
    self.selectedIndexes.removeAllObjects()
    collectionView.reloadData()        
}
```

I must also point out that `UICollectionView` has a private `variable` called `indexPathsForSelectedItems: [IndexPath]?` that can be used for this type of implementations, and in combination with overriding `setSelected()` in `UICollectionViewCell` can make your code a lot `lighter`. Personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

i am not that much use to to swift but its all logical, so i can give you idea

1. create a NSMutableArray
2. add indexPath in didSelectRow method
3. before adding anything remove objects from that array (use count to get number of objects)
4. reload the table

NOTE: add check in cellForRow method if array contains indexPath then add the boundary else dont

when cancel is pressed you can empty the array and reload the collection view